# How to get the Locale of a NumberFormat in Java/Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, locale, number-formatting

According to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html, `NumberFormat.getInstance()` will get you a `NumberFormat` instance in the current locale. I would like to verify after creating the instance what the locale is using a method like `getLocale()`, but no such method seems to be documented there.

The best I could do to ascertain this was to call `Locale.getDefault()` in the Kotlin shell (`kotlinc`):

```java
>>> import java.math.BigDecimal
>>> import java.text.NumberFormat
>>> NumberFormat.getInstance().format(BigDecimal(1500))
1,500
>>> import java.util.Locale
>>> Locale.getDefault()
en_US
```

Is there no `NumberFormat.getLocale()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there no `NumberFormat.getLocale()` method?

There is not - what you can do, though is call the same method that `NumberFormat.getInstance()` does under the hood:

```
Locale defaultLocale = Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT);
```

There are two `Category`'s in Java 8: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.Category.html. If you need the `DISPLAY` one, just swap out the arg.